# Oracle APEX. New installation. Unable to create WorkSpace: PROVISION_COMPANY

Tags: oracle, oracle-apex-5

Newly installed Oracle Database 12c. While creating first Workspace in Application Express (APEX) 5.1 I've got an error: "Error provisioning XXXXXXXXXXXX.
ORA-20001: Request 1824748984765804 could not be processed. PROVISION_COMPANY"
What could it mean "PROVISION_COMPANY"?

Comment: Did you manage to cope with that error?